# Unable to pass the same object with different result to partial view on the Home/Index controller in mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<pInfo> pobj = new List<pInfo>();
        pobj = (from pid in db.pInfoes
                orderby pid.pId  descending
                select pid).ToList();
        return View(pobj);

    }


public ActionResult toprank() ///partial view 
    {
        List<pInfo> pobj = new List<pInfo>();
        pobj = (from pid in db.pInfoes.Where(c => c.DateCreated < DateTime.Now)
                orderby pid.Score descending
                select pid).Take(3).ToList();
        return PartialView("toprank", pobj);
    }

 \\\ Index.csHtml
  @model IEnumerable<TestProj.pInfo>
  <table>
 <tr>
 <td>
 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <iframe width="560" 
            height="300" 
            src="@item.pUrl"
             frameborder="0"></iframe>    
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
}
</td>
<td>
@{Html.RenderPartial("toprank", model);}
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I am passing different result set for same Model i.e pInfo. on partial view and Index actionresult on the Home Controller. When I am trying to render the partial view on the Index view page I am getting the same result-set from the Index action result two times one in the table and another in the   @{Html.RenderPartial("toprank", model);} ... I am sure I am missing some basic understanding of how the partial view works but unable to figure it out for last 3 hrs. If I change the url to partial view i.e (home/toprank  ) then I get the resultset I want but its not coming on the Home/Index page

Please let me know if my design concept is wrong.. I am starting to feel that this is probably the wrong approach to get this working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to see the toprank() called you need to use Html.Action not partial, change the view  to this :

```
<td>
  @Html.Action("toprank")
</td>
```

Comment: OMG this works.. I am not understanding this... wats wrong with render.partial.. anyways thanks a lot for the concern..

Comment: you are welcomed ;) render Partial only goes and finds the view and pass the Model to it, html.action calls the action in controller and controller does what it supposed to do. there is no action involved in using renderPartial.